# Custom WP query with polylang term

Tags: wp-query

i am banging my head on how should the mysql query be correctly defined.
I have term_taxonomy_id id defined for polylang languages 2 and 9
I want to return ONLY return posts, who has term_taxonomy_id 2 (primary language) AND then from the result all posts who has term_taxonomy_id 32,71,38.
Can you help me on this? Where i am wrong on this query?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    agn_posts.ID,
    agn_posts.post_title,
    agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
FROM
    agn_posts
LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships ON(
        agn_posts.ID = agn_term_relationships.object_id
    )
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND(
        agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN(32) 
        OR agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN(71)
        OR agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN(38)
        )
    AND agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN(2)
        
    AND agn_posts.post_type = 'property' AND(
        agn_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR agn_posts.post_status = 'private'
    )
GROUP BY
    agn_posts.ID
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Why are you not using `new WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`?

Comment: I am using, but the "lang" argument does not work somehow. Here https://github.com/jamajamajaaama/test/blob/main/similar-properties.php on the line 15 I added the parameter lang, but wpQuery on line 121 does not take that param somewhat. So I tried to appent tax_query as polylang keeps the languages in taxonomies on line 111, outputed the query and it did not work weel. So with that query above , I am trying to debug the code :)

Comment: You could try suppressing filters, e.g. use `get_posts()` instead of `WP_Query`. And what's the output of `echo $similar_properties_query->request; ` ? Have you tried running it via phpMyAdmin or direct `$wpdb->query()` call, and did it return any results?

Comment: I tried to echo the SQL query, but it included all posts with term_taxonomy in 32.71,38 AND 2. I need to get posts who has term_tax id 32,71,38 from those who has term_tax id 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised Answer

If the terms `2`, `32`, `71` and `38` belong in the same taxonomy like `language`, then see my original answer.

Otherwise, the `WP_Query` would be like so:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND', // for clauses 1 and 2
        [ // clause 1
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'terms'    => 2,
        ],
        [ // clause 2
            'relation' => 'OR', // for sub-clauses 1, 2 and 3
            [ // sub-clause 1
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
                'terms'    => 32,
            ],
            [ // sub-clause 2
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name-2',
                'terms'    => 71,
            ],
            [ // sub-clause 3
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name-3',
                'terms'    => 38,
            ],
        ],
    ],
] );
```

That should give you the correct `IN() AND ( IN() OR IN() OR IN() )` query, and as for the SQL command, just do `echo $query->request;` and then do whatever needed with the command. :)

And be sure to replace the *taxonomy names* with the correct ones.

### Original Answer

Note that I did not test [your code on GitHub](https://github.com/jamajamajaaama/test/blob/main/similar-properties.php), but what you're trying to do:

- Query posts in that are assigned to the term `2`
- *And then* those assigned to the terms `32`, `71`, `38`

Can be easily achived in `WP_Query` via the `tax_query` parameter, like so:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND', // AND is the default
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'terms'    => 2,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'terms'    => [ 32, 71, 38 ],
        ],
    ],
] );
```

And if you inspect the SQL command from the above query, i.e. `echo $query->request`, the command has two `LEFT JOIN` clauses:

```sql
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
```

And the `WHERE` for the `tax_query` would look like:

```sql
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2)
AND
tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (32,71,38)
```

So that's how your SQL command should look like — i.e. use two (LEFT/INNER/etc.) JOINs with the first one for querying posts in the term `2`, and the second one for posts in the terms `32`, `71` and/or `38`.

Here's an example based on your SQL command, except (just like above), I used the prefix `wp_` instead of `agn_`, and I also used table aliases like `p` for `wp_posts`:

(Note that in this example, I intentionally didn't use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`)

```sql
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, tr.term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr2 ON p.ID = tr2.object_id
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND tr.term_taxonomy_id IN(2)
  AND tr2.term_taxonomy_id IN(32, 71, 38)
  AND p.post_type = 'property'
  AND (p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY RAND() # note that this can get VERY slow on large data/tables
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Thank you Sally. this seems as a logical explanation as I can probably expect. T with the only drawback, that the second part terms'    => [ 32, 71, 38 ], should be in OR relationship with each other.

Comment: That will by default generate a `IN (32,71,38)` query, which queries posts assigned to any of that terms - i.e. something like `term_taxonomy_id = 32 OR 71 OR 38`. Or am I not understanding what you mean?

Comment: At the beginning I want to select al posts assigned to term 2 and then from those one select posts assigned to 32 OR 71 OR 38. I thing I found a clue in bottom example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870678/wordpress-custom-tax-query-with-multiple-conditions-not-working  i

Comment: How about just trying the code in my answer, the one using `WP_Query`. Because it does what you've just and already explained, and a basic example would always be a good starting point. Then you can always later on extend the query args as needed.

Comment: Thanks man, the problem is I need to adjust the code in github to work for my site, but anyway, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: You'll have to do that on your own or post a separate question specific to the [`WP_Query` code](https://github.com/jamajamajaaama/test/blob/main/similar-properties.php), but if my answer help you with the SQL command, then I'd appreciate if you can upvote my answer - and actually, you could just copy the command, change the table prefix and run in in phpMyAdmin, then see if you get the expected results.

Comment: Sally, I updated my question in another thread if you are interested in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660235/mixed-or-and-taxonomy-query

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really notice the terms are of different taxonomy (`property-xx`) - no wonder you wanted the `IN() OR IN() OR..` :) Anyway, check my answer there on SO and let me know - or I hope it works for you!